# vba update pivot items

Tags: vba, excel

i have a report that goes through and changes various pivot fields and copies some of the data to another sheet. I made a macro for it that works, however it is essentially just the results of recorded my clicks. I would like to write a sub that I can pass in a pivot table, pivot field and an pivot item name and have it update the fields that way instead of copying and pasting the actions over and over. Here is one piece of it that sets three filters in the pivot table.

```
`Worksheets("Closed Pivot").Activate
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Business")
        .PivotItems("NEW").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Pre-Paid Maint").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Renewal").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Training / Pro Svc").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Upsell/Cross-sell").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("#N/A").Visible = False
    End With
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Stage"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Revenue Channel")
        .PivotItems("2-Tier Distributor").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Direct Sales").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Direct VAR").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Ecommerce").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Maintenance Renewal").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Stage")
        .PivotItems("Closed Lost").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Closed Won").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With`
```

Comment: Do you want to actually pass the PivotTable, PivotField and PivotItem objects or do you want to reference them by name? Also, how do you intent to pass these variables? From the UI or through VBA? In other words, where do you get the input for the routine you need? Hint: your own question already states you need: `Sub FilterPivot(pt as PivotTable, pf as PivotField, pi as PivotItem)` or alternatively `Sub FilterPivot(ptStr as string, pfStr as string, piStr as string)`

Comment: my original thought was to pass them by value and have them called within the vba code since once it is done it will run the same way, but i dont know if passing just the references would work better

Comment: Well this does not really matter. The question is whether you want to pass the pivottables themselves (since they're objects, ByVal or ByRef won't matter, since VBA will pass a reference anyway) or strings that the routine will use to find the appropriate pivottable, fields, etc. Please show me what you have programmed so far on top of the recorded sample above and I'll try my best to help you out.

Comment: i was trying to do something like this where it loops through the items and checks them                                                                                                          Sub updatePivot(pvttable As pivottable, pvtfld As pivotfield, pvtitm As pivotitem)
For Each i In pvttable.pvtfld.PivotItems
If i = pvtitm Then
pvttable.pvtfld.pvtitm.Value = True
Else: pvttable.pvtfld.pvtitm.Value = False
End If
Next i

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two options: Either you pass the names of the pivottables, fields and items as strings to the sub, or you pass the objects themselves.
When passing the names as strings:

```
Sub FilterPivotByNames(wsStr as string, ptStr as string, pfStr as string, piStr as string)
Dim ws as Worksheet 
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField
Dim pi as PivotItem

Set ws = Worksheets(wsStr)
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(ptStr)
Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfStr)

With pf
    For each pi in pf.PivotItems
        If pi.name = piStr Then
             pi.Visible = True
        Else
             pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End With

End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Sub test()
FilterPivotByNames "Sheet1", "PivotTable5", "Stage", "Closed Won" 'Just send the names as parameters; the FilterPivotByNames routine knows how to find the appropriate object.
End Sub
```

When passing the objects themselves:

```
Sub FilterPivotByObject(pt as PivotTable, pf as PivotField, pi as PivotItem)
Dim pItem as PivotItem
For each pItem in pt.pf.PivotItems
    If pItem = pi then 
        pItem.visible = True
    Else
        pItem.visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Sub test2()
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField
Dim pi as PivotItem
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable5")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Stage")
Set pi = pf.PivotItem("Closed Won")
FilterPivotByObject(pt, pf, pi) 'In this scenario we first make sure we have the pivottables in variables and use those as the parameters, instead of just the names.
End Sub
```

You might want to expand on these for multivalue filters, etc. Also some error handling might be in order, depending on who will use the subs. Unexpected values will lead to errors (e.g. when PivotTable5 on Worksheet1 does not exist)